# UITextFields inside UITableViewCells - text disappears when cells go out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with bunch of `UITableViewCell`s. These `UITableViewCell`s have multiple `UITextField`s inside them.

Now every time I scroll up and down, and the `UITableViewCell`s go out of the view, and come back in, whatever text I had entered inside the `UITextField` disappears. What is the best way to make this work?

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

ComplaintsCustomCell *cell=(ComplaintsCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil){
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ComplaintsCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){

        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell = (ComplaintsCustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

cell.durationFld.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Duration"];
[cell.durationFld setTag:indexPath.row + 5000];
```

Comment: put code of cellForRowAtindexpath

Comment: I think you have written the textfield allocation code outside the if (cell == nil) condition

Comment: once check your cellIdentifier.

Comment: can you post cellForRowAtIndexPath code here.I think resuse issues

Comment: Where do you get that version of loadNibNamed?  It doesn't appear to be the Apple standard issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have two issues:

1. You're setting all your cells' text fields to the exact same value of `[dict valueForKey:@"Duration"]`
2. It appears that `[dict valueForKey:@"Duration"]` actually has no value, which explains why the text fields are empty as soon as your code is called again.

I think you should create a simple class that has a property to replan NSArray and initialize it with whatever the initial values of the text fields are. Whenever a text field changes, just replace the array object at the same index of indexPath.row with the new text. In your original cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you should assign the text field's text like this:

```
cell.durationFld.text = [valuesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If you deal with a lot of text fields, I'd also strongly recommend taking a look at the free Sensible TableView framework. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

create an `NSMutableArray` which at each position, holds an `NSString` object which matches each cell.

when you config + show each cell in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, set the text of the UITextField to the string in the array at position indexPath.row.

when editing a `UITextField`, insert/update the `NSString` object at the current `indexPath.row` position in the array

Answer (score -1):

**General Suggestion:**

Put/Create `UITextField`  in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and add with

```
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textFieldName]
```

This code write between

```
if(cell == nil)
 { 
     // put UITextField here
 }
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.